# how to collect all files, that are opened by linux application

Tags: linux, strace

I want to collect a list of all files, that are opened by an application (in my case, it's a s/w bulder).

'strace -f' fails, because it mixes continuos opening from different forks, for example:

```
13078 open("file1", O_RDONLY <unfinished ...>
13077 open("file2", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
13078 <... open resumed> )              = 3
```

and I cannot track, if the "file1" is actually opened or failed with E_NOENT.

'strace -ff' is also fails, as it creates too many files (application makes really large number of subprocesses), and it creates program.${pid}, program.${pid+1}, and so on, an after approx 32k forks it again creates and rewrites program.${pid}, program.${pid+1}. I can google how to increase process numbering, but anyway I don't want this bulk of multitude files.

So the question is, can I solve this problem quick and dirty with strace or other tool?

Answer (score 1):

`strace -f -eopen /path/to/cmd args ... 2>&1 | gzip > output.log.gz`

---

If you're looking for a specific process and not *all* the children, then:

`gunzip output.log.gz | head -n500 | less`

Read the file until you find the Process ID (pid) of the particular program you are looking for, then use `grep`.

---

If you're looking for specific results (such as the absence of ENOENT), you can grep them out:

`zgrep --invert-match ENOENT output.log.gz | less`

Comment: This doesn't work. As I mentioned, the problem is that the logged syscall (e.g. open()) and its result (= 1 or = -1, as ENOENT) goes in log in different lines, mixed with other syscalls, so I can't grep  failed open() on all nonexistent files, with any regexp, for example 'open.*ENOENT'. Disk space is enough, so gzipping is not needed anyway.

Comment: All I've got with 'strace -f' and 'grep' is a bulk of useless strings, like `open("file1", O_RDONLY <unfinished ...>`, so I can't automatically determine, is it really was open or not, so I can't automatically get list of all opened files or list of failed open attempts. The log is very huge, so handworking is unacceptable.